# jQuery emptying wrong div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been working on a filter plugin using HTML5's data-* attribute, but jQuery (or something) keeps emptying the wrong div.

Basically I have two divs with different classes. '.gallery-source' is the class of the div with ALL of the content (and the 'display' property is set to 'none' value, so it doesn't show up in the document); while '.gallery' on the first hand is empty but then given the contents of '.gallery-source'.

Once the user has selected options to filter in the dropdowns (an unordered list of items, with links that have data-* values matching some of the contents of '.gallery-source' data-* values), the '.gallery' div is emptied and then each matching content (same data-* values as set in the dropdowns) of '.gallery-source' is appended inside '.gallery'.

The code looks something like this:

```
    // Append everything from .gallery-source to .gallery in order to show ALL work (filters may be applied later)
    var gallerySource = $('.works-content .gallery-source').html();
    $('.works-content .gallery').html(gallerySource);

    // Attribute filtering for all work inside .gallery
    $('ul#artist-dropdown li a, ul#technique-dropdown li a, ul#material-dropdown li a').on('click', function() {

      // Get  selected filter on form
      var artistFilterValue    = $('.works-content .filter-dropdowns .dropdown-wrapper a.button.artist > span').attr('data-filter-artist');
      var techniqueFilterValue = $('.works-content .filter-dropdowns .dropdown-wrapper a.button.technique > span').attr('data-filter-technique');
      var materialFilterValue  = $('.works-content .filter-dropdowns .dropdown-wrapper a.button.material > span').attr('data-filter-material');

      // Empty .gallery in order to fill it later with filtered work
      $('.works-content .gallery').empty();

      // Get filtered elements and append them to .gallery
      $('.single-work[data-artist~="' + artistFilterValue + '"][data-technique~="' + techniqueFilterValue + '"][data-material~="' + materialFilterValue + '"]').each(function(){
        $('.works-content .gallery').append($(this));
      });
    });
```

The document initially looks like this (both '.gallery' and '.gallery-source' are populated):

```
<div class="row works-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns filter-dropdowns">
      <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
        Filtrar por:
        <span class="dropdown-label">Artista</span>
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="artist-dropdown" class="small button radius dropdown artist"><span data-filter-artist="all">Seleccionar</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a><br>
        <ul id="artist-dropdown" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-artist="all">Todos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-artist="name-one">Name One</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-artist="name-two">Name Two</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
        Técnica:
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="technique-dropdown" class="small button radius dropdown technique"><span data-filter-technique="all">Seleccionar</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a><br>
        <ul id="technique-dropdown" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-technique="all">Todos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-technique="acrylic">Acrílico</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-technique="mixed-paper">Mixta sobre papel</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-technique="mixed-fabric">Mixta sobre tela</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-technique="oil">Óleo</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
        Soporte:
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="material-dropdown" class="small button radius dropdown material"><span data-filter-material="all">Seleccionar</span> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a><br>
        <ul id="material-dropdown" data-dropdown-content="" class="f-dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-material="all">Todos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-material="fabric">Tela</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span data-filter-material="paper">Papel</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <ul class="button-group filter-buttons">
        <li class="active show-all"><a href="#" class="button">Todas</a></li>
        <li class="show-available"><a href="#" class="button">Disponibles</a></li>
        <li class="show-sold"><a href="#" class="button">Vendidas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row gallery-source">
    <div data-artist="name-one all" data-technique="oil all" data-material="paper all" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns single-work available-work">
      <a class="work-lightbox" href="img/work/name-one/3.jpg">
        <div class="work-image-wrapper">
          <div class="work-image" style="background-image: url(img/work/name-one/3.jpg);"></div>
        </div>

        <img class="avatar" src="img/artists/name-one.png">
      </a>

      <a href="" class="artist-name">
        <h2>Name One <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2>
      </a>
      <ul class="details">
        <li class="title">"Título de obra"</li>
        <li>Código SUA1005</li>
        <li>Tamaño: 140 x 180 cm.</li>
        <li>Soporte: Papel</li>
        <li>Técnica: Óleo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-artist="name-two all" data-technique="acrylic all" data-material="fabric all" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns end single-work sold-work">
      <a class="work-lightbox" href="img/work/name-two/5.jpg">
        <img class="sold" src="img/work/sold.png">

        <div class="work-image-wrapper">
          <div class="work-image" style="background-image: url(img/work/name-two/5.jpg);"></div>
        </div>

        <img class="avatar" src="img/artists/name-two.png">
      </a>

      <a href="" class="artist-name">
        <h2>Name Two <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2>
      </a>
      <ul class="details">
        <li class="title">"Título de obra"</li>
        <li>Código SUA1005</li>
        <li>Tamaño: 140 x 180 cm.</li>
        <li>Soporte: Tela</li>
        <li>Técnica: Acrílico</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row gallery">
    <div data-artist="name-one all" data-technique="oil all" data-material="paper all" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns single-work available-work">
      <a class="work-lightbox" href="img/work/name-one/3.jpg">
        <div class="work-image-wrapper">
          <div class="work-image" style="background-image: url(img/work/name-one/3.jpg);"></div>
        </div>

        <img class="avatar" src="img/artists/name-one.png">
      </a>

      <a href="" class="artist-name">
        <h2>Name One <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2>
      </a>
      <ul class="details">
        <li class="title">"Título de Obra"</li>
        <li>Código ejemplo</li>
        <li>Tamaño: 140 x 180 cm.</li>
        <li>Soporte: Papel</li>
        <li>Técnica: Óleo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-artist="name-two all" data-technique="acrylic all" data-material="fabric all" class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns end single-work sold-work">
      <a class="work-lightbox" href="img/work/name-two/5.jpg">
        <img class="sold" src="img/work/sold.png">

        <div class="work-image-wrapper">
          <div class="work-image" style="background-image: url(img/work/name-two/5.jpg);"></div>
        </div>

        <img class="avatar" src="img/artists/name-two.png">
      </a>

      <a href="" class="artist-name">
        <h2>Name Two <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h2>
      </a>
      <ul class="details">
        <li class="title">"Título de obra"</li>
        <li>Código ejempl5</li>
        <li>Tamaño: 140 x 180 cm.</li>
        <li>Soporte: Tela</li>
        <li>Técnica: Acrílico</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But after selecting an option in one of the filter dropdowns, '.gallery-source' is empty :(

What am I missing here? I think I'm going crazy!

Anyway, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: check to put console.log() before this line. $('.works-content .gallery').append($(this));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append` moves the entire node from `.gallery-source` to `.gallery`. You want to do this instead:

```
$(this).clone().appendTo('.works-content .gallery');
```

You can [read about `.clone()` here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

[Here's a jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/P944A/)

Comment: It did the trick, I didn't know .append() moved the entire node. Thank you so so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

The [API docs](https://api.jquery.com/empty) of `empty` also say:

> ... If we had any number of nested elements inside `<div class="hello">`, they would be removed, too.

So your `$('.works-content .gallery').empty()` may remove more than you want it to.